# How to maintain the width after adding icon next to dropdown list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Based on my code, is there any way to make the dropdown list align with the other input fields?

I need to add an icon right next to the dropdown list. However, `class="form-control"` should be 100% width by default but it doesn't after I added the icon.

[image: screenshot]

```
<form asp-action="Apply" asp-controller="Jobs">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="YearsAttended" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="YearsAttended" class="form-control" min="0" value="0"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="HighestQualification" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10 form-inline">
            <select asp-for="HighestQualification" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<QualificationLevel>()" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Choose one...</option>
            </select>
            <a href='#'><i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: middle;">help</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably best making use of [Input Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic) provided by bootstrap.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="HighestQualification" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-inline input-group">
            <select asp-for="HighestQualification" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<QualificationLevel>()" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Choose one...</option>
            </select>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <a href='#' >
                    <i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align: middle;">help</i>
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then adjust the `input-group-addon` styling to remove the "grey" that comes default

**CSS**

```
.input-group-addon {
    padding: 0 6px;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0zsmg2d7/)**