# Using flag icon with the language selector dynamically with cultures

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I am using the select language dropdown but I want to add a flag to it for the culture info of each of the countries that I am supporting is there anyway of adding the flag dynamically using flag icon

Flag Icon : https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}

<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="MISObjects" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl"
          method="post" role="form">
        <label asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name">@Localizer["Language:"]</label> <select name="culture"
                                                                                                               onchange="this.form.submit();"
                                                                                                               asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems">
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Ok i have the icons showing in the dropdown but its repeating the languges obv as its getting it from asp-items and the javascript but if I remove the asp-items it wont work.

```
<script>
   $(function () {
     //Initialize Select2 Elements
     $('.select2').select2()
     var isoCountries = [                    
        { id: 'FR', text: 'France' },
        { id: 'ES', text: 'Spain' },
        { id: 'GB', text: 'United Kingdom' },
        { id: 'US', text: 'United States' }                    
        ];

     function formatCountry(country) {
      if (!country.id) { return country.text; }
         var $country = $(
           '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-' + country.id.toLowerCase() + ' flag-icon-squared"></span>' +
           '<span class="flag-text">' + country.text + "</span>"
         );
        return $country;
     };
     //Assuming you have a select element with name country
       $("[name='culture']").select2({
                autoWidth:true,
                placeholder: "Please Select a country",
                templateResult: formatCountry,
                data: isoCountries
            });
            $("#culture").select2({ dropdownCssClass: 'bigdrop' }); 


     });
</script>
```

Comment: the link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687259/how-to-maintain-the-width-after-adding-icon-next-to-dropdown-list

Comment: No its not relvant its nothing about the width or that icon set shown in that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('select[name ="culture"] > option' ).each(function() {
   
     
    var country = $(
           '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-' + country.id.toLowerCase() + ' flag-icon-squared"></span>' +
           '<span class="flag-text">' + country.text + "</span>"
         ); 
     $(this).html(country); 
     }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked a charm i hate javascript but needs must.

Comment: How do I ensure the culture code get sent back properly to the set langue do i need ot change anything above to make that happen

Comment: just check the option value ,if option value do not have any changes happen ,then no need .